# Angular - Unit Testing Controllers

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-controller

I have written some unit tests for a simple controller that has a service that makes a http request, both unit tests are working but I am not sure which is the most appropriate or if I would want to use both?

The first test I wrote is more like the mockito style tests for spring controllers in java:

```
  it('should make call via function add() using spyOn()', function() {                                      
        spyOn(calculatorServiceMock, 'add').and.returnValue($q.when(5));
        $scope.add(3,2);    
        $httpBackend.flush();           
        expect(calculatorServiceMock.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith(3, 2);          
        expect($scope.result).toEqual(5); 
 });
```

The second test is I guess a little more simple, it doesnt verify any interactions inside the controller it just expects a call to be made, stubs the response and checks a value on the controller afterwards:

```
it('should make call via function add() using http backend expect', function() {                                     
      $httpBackend.expect('GET', url + 'calculator/add?val1=1&val2=32').respond({"result": 33});           
      $scope.add(1, 32);          
      $httpBackend.flush();               
      expect($scope.result).toEqual(33); 
 });
```

Is either of these methods preferred over the other and is there any merit to including both to test a controller function?

Comment: Never got an answer to this?